# Learning Rails: Downgrade to 3.x and Ruby 1.9.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, downgrade

I am rather new to Rails. What I have found is that most tutorials/screencasts were published when Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9 were the latest versions. Do you folks recommend I downgrade my versions for the purpose of learning the framework?

I understand that this question is fairly open-ended, and there is no "real" answer, but I am sure that the answers you all give will provide those who are facing the same question.

Comment: Downgrade rails to 3.x as 4 is significantly different, but your ruby should be fine at 1.9 or 2.

Comment: Okay, great. Thank you. Mind putting this comment as an answer, so I can declare my question answered? @DashControl

Comment: Sure. It has been added as answer.  I'm glad it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade rails to 3.x as 4 is significantly different, but your ruby should be fine at 1.9 or 2.

That has been my experience with rails at least.  I was trying to follow quite few rails casts prior to rails 4, while using rails 4 and had a horrible time of it.  Once downgrading to rails 3, it was a much better learning experience.

Hope that helps